# Compiling Visual C++ Project on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, cmake

I am tring to port [this code](http://www.loni.ucla.edu/~ztu/publication/seg_code_release.zip) to Linux

I believe OpenCV uses cmake to compile a VC++ code base in Linux, you create a dir, in that dir do cmake..., and a Makefile is generated. But I guess I would need a VC++ makefile first. My request is, at the very least, a VC++ makefile for the project above, and show it compiles the project with g++. If you can think of a general way, a tool that compile VC++, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake generates Makefile or VC++ project depending on your platform, so you'll end with a Makefile after running CMake.

However the code you mention isn't using neither OpenCV nor CMake, so I may be missing something...

There is some old tool called dsp2make for converting VC++6 to Makefile, but I doubt it'll be no-brainer. Better start with a CMakeLists.txt and list the cpp files you want to compile.

Comment: OpenCV was just an example I used cmake on, that's all